# How to make dynamic background image on website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want't to make dynamic background image on website. I want to change size like this [changemarks.com](http://www.changemakrs.com/)

Please tell me where to start?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamic? All I see on that link is a large, fixed background image...

Comment: The background image size changes when the window size changes. I wanted to do this implementation. Thanks.

Comment: I see. That's an easy effect to achieve. One way to do this is to position the image behind the main container, set the image to fixed position, and 100% width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery animation/effects: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

To set size of the background dynamically:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background: url(urlhere) no-repeat 100% 100%"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to know dynamic size change. I edited my question. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code, but the image doesn't widen to the edges of the window. I alternately find out [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/). All I wanted to do is this ><.

It was really simple!! And your jQuery recommendation will be my next subject. Thanks!

Comment: I also find out http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/ . It seems there are many libraries like this. Good.:)

Answer (score 0):

That background is actually a slideshow positioned to fill the entire window. There are tons of free slideshow JavaScript libraries out there you can use.

It's also dead-simple to write your own using jQuery animations to fade in and out each successive image in the animation.

Comment: I also find out vegas.jaysalvat.com . It seems there are many libraries like this. I'll search the one which meet my need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

They give you a framework for setting up your CSS to be static or responsive. If you want the image to change size when the window resizes, then you want "responsive", which basically uses CSS media queries and other logic to perform certain functions when the viewport reaches a minimum size.

[Check out responsive design here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)

It also makes layout much simpler because it gives you columns to align your data in.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I use bootstrap a little. I try to do it by bootstrap!